# How do I overlay a toast on top of a current page

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement my own toast and I want to know how I can overlay the toast on top of the current page, by doing something like

```
MyToast.show(context, message, Duration(seconds: 2));
```

The thing is I want to build my own toast package. Also, I want the toast to stay active even when the page has been popped but will only disappear when the duration is up.

Comment: You can use Overlay apis.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out